# How to test a WebKit nightly build?

Tags: webkit

I would like to test the nightly version of WebKit on Windows, but I couldn't find anything about HOW to do it.
I tried all the executables inside the downloaded .zip but they all complain that my configuration is wrong.
What is the recommended way to test a WebKit nightly on Windows?

Comment: Do you have Safari installed? I believe in order to use webkit nighty builds then you need to have certain libraries installed on your computer. These libraries are included when you install Safari.

Comment: I see, you have to install Safari then... I'll try, thanks :)

Comment: @Thomas Clayson: Well it does start this way, and the user agent becomes "AppleWebKit/534+" instead of the 534.57.2 of the "vanilla" Safari 5.1.7. So it looks like this is how you do it... Care to write an answer which I'll accept right away? :)

Comment: Done see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Safari on your computer. There are certain libraries which webkit needs which are installed on your computer when you install Safari.

Comment: So according to http://superuser.com/a/483077/2226 it looks like *at the moment* this does work, but is not guaranteed

Answer (score 1):

Alexey Proskuryakov of the WebKit team told me:

> I think that nightlies still happen to work on Windows for now, so
>   what you mentioned should do it. We don't put any effort in making
>   nightlies work with anything but the latest Safari release however,
>   which is currently 6.0.1.

Comment: And yet they still require people to test bugs in Webkit Nightly before reporting them. How are they supposed to do it if they're not on a Mac?

Comment: Yeah, I had to find someone willing to lend me their Mac :( Apart from this, the people on the Webkit Bugzilla are amazingly helpful